# How to solve $x^3 = x^{x^2-2x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Well i guess this is somehow pretty easy but there is something i don't understand.

I know that if $\;x>0\;$ then I can compare the exponents: $\; 3=x^2-2x$ , and from here I get that $\;x=3\; or \;x=-1\;$, but because $\;x>0\;$ that leaves me only with $\;x=3$ .

Second thing is that if both bases from both sides are equal to $1$ then its another solution, and therefore $\;x=1\;$ is another solution.

For conclusion we get that the solutions are: $\;x=3\; or \;x=1$ .

Now my question is why $\;x=-1\;$ is also a solution? How do i get to this solution? am I suppose to just try place it and check because I somehow got it for $\;x>0$ ? are there any steps I can follow for solving this kind of equations?

Another question is how do you call this kind of equation? when I was looking for "exponential equations" I could only find ones with numbers in the bases .

Thanks!

Comment: $(-1)^x = (-1)^y$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are positive numbers having the same parity. Now $x^2-2x$ at $x=-1$ has the value $1$, hence odd parity, while $3$ also has odd parity. Hence $-1$ satisfies this equation.

Comment: Ok but how did you get to this $x=-1$?, I know its a solution but how do you find it? I mean, $x^2-2x$ is odd for many numbers, I would even guess that it is for every odd number you place there.

Comment: The function on the right hand side is interesting. Wolfram Alpha and Desmos give it a real domain $x>0$ but clearly there are negative values that work. I'll have to examine it more closely to find the full real domain.

Comment: "I know that if $x>0$ then I can compare the exponents". This is an oversimplification. Consider $x=1>0$. That is a solution even though the exponents do not match.

Answer (score 3):

One approach. Note that $0$ is not a solution, if you follow the convention that $0^0=1$. So in the following, we may take the logarithm of $|x|$.

$$\begin{align}
x^3&=x^{x^2-2x}\\
\implies \left\lvert x^3\right\rvert&=\left\lvert x^{x^2-2x}\right\rvert\\
\implies |x|^3&=|x|^{x^2-2x}\\
\implies 3\ln|x|&=\left(x^2-2x\right)\ln|x|\\
\implies 0&=\left(x^2-2x-3\right)\ln|x|\\
\implies 0&=(x-3)(x+1)\ln|x|\\
\end{align}$$

So either $x=3$, $x=-1$, or $\ln|x|=0$. This last condition implies either $x=1$ or $x=-1$.

So (since this used one-way implications) there are three candidate solutions: $\{3,-1,1\}$. Then you can verify directly that each one is indeed a solution.

In the particular case of $-1$:  $$(-1)^3\stackrel{?}{=}(-1)^{(-1)^2-2(-1)}$$ is just true.

Answer (score 0):

$x^a=x^b\implies a=b$ for all $x$,whether $x>0$ or $x<0$. You got $3=x^2-2x$, and solved this quadratic equation to get $x\in\{3,-1\}$. So $-1$ is indeed a solution. It depends on the equation as to which methods will you follow, there is no general algorithm. But yes, keep using exponent rules, and you will eventually lead to a solution.

Comment: $1^{23}=1^{47}$. And $(-1)^{23}=(-1)^{47}$.  Yet $23\neq47$.

Comment: And of course $x=1$ is a solution, so there is more to the story with OP's original equaton than just $\{3,-1\}$ as the solution set.

Answer (score -4):

look on rh(n)
and get x^2-2*x=3 (mod n)
Because rh(2)=-1 then we get 
(-1)^2+2=3=3 (mod 2)
and thats why it true